# vuex unknown action type: displayArticles

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vuex

Why it doesn't display the json coming from [jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos)?
Did I miss something here? This is just my first time using Vuex.

By the way, I separated the files so that I can debug it easily and I thought it's a good practice for me because I'm planning to implement vuex in a bigger project.
Here is my index.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import articles from './modules/articles';

//Load Vuex
Vue.use(Vuex);

//Create store
export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        articles
    }
})
```

Here is my articles.js .

```
 import axios from 'axios';

//state
const state = {
    articles: []
};

//actions
const actions = {
    loadArticles({ commit }) {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
            .then(response => response.data)
            .then(articles => {
                commit('displayArticles', articles,
                console.log(articles))
            })
    }
};

//mutations
const mutations = {
    displayArticles(state, articles) {
        state.articles = articles;
    }
};

//export 
export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

and lastly my home.vue that will display the data from the vuex:

```
  <template>
  <section>
    <h1>HI</h1>
    <h1 v-for="article in articles" :key="article.id">{{article.id}}</h1>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("displayArticles");
  },
  computed: mapState(["articles"])
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to dispatch the action, so in your .vue file you have to write :

```
mounted() {
      this.$store.dispatch("loadArticles");
    },
```

and to get the list of articles in your component you should use getter in your Store:

```
const getters = {
  getArticles: state => {
    return state.articles;
  }
```

and the computed will be like this:

```
    computed:{
      getArticlesFromStore(){
        return this.$store.getters.getArticles;
      }
    }
```

and then you call the computed leement in your HTML:

```
    <h1 v-for="article in getArticlesFromStore" :key="article.id">{{article.id}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to dispatch mutation. You need to use commit with mutations or move your displayArticles to actions. I imagine you meant to dispatch loadArticles?